# Thinking of going SQLIte over Access for a small office Excel app

Tags: excel, sqlite, ms-access

Client wants to go with Access to aggregate Excel data, but I start wondering - how do I gauge whether Access is to fat and SQLite is just right?

Comment: Does the client trust you to make the decision, or has the client already decided?

Comment: The client trusts me, but the one sticking point might be if the client wants to use Access as a reporting engine or to shorcut the data entry with quick forms. This is a law office, so maybe I should just stick with Access, and revolutionize the field later.

Comment: If you want a more robust back-end for Access, you might like to consider SQL Express, it is free and works well with an Access front-end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQLite is essentially one product. Access is at least four.

1. Multi-user SQL(ish) dbms
2. RAD environment for user-interface development
3. Reporting engine
4. Programming environment

Law offices are not paperless offices. Reporting is going to be a big deal. And Access has one of the best report generators I've ever worked with, and I've been around a long time. (Too long, some say.)

Comment: Me too. I always wondered why the other reporting products were so gigantic and bloated. Point well taken.